# HTML/CSS : Set width & height of object in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, load

I have ran into a problem when trying to load html files into a div tag, using the code below;

```
<div id ="content" ></div>
<script>
function load_home(){
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="home.html"></object>';
}
</script>
```

The problem is that the content gets loaded as seen below;
[image]

The content doesn't fill the width or height of the screen.

Any tips for making the loaded html file, fill the body width and height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the width and height parameters if the object tag:

```
...
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="home.html" style="width:100%; height: 100%;"></object>';
...
```

**edit:**
  With respect to the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zYw3S/12/ adding

```
#content{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 70vh;
}
```

Comment: I just added that width & height values, the loaded content now fills the entire body area, but the height is still messed up.

Comment: You're saying the body of the document doesn't take up the entirety of the browser?  I think you'll need to post some more of your document.  As a simple doc such as this: `<html>
<body onload="load_home()">
<div id ="content" ></div>
<script>
function load_home(){
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="home.html" style="width:100%; height: 100%;"></object>';
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
` Will fill the screen

Comment: Its not that the body tag doesn't take up the entire page, its that the object tag that gets created doesn't take up the width or height of the page. I think I've fixed it though, by doing style="position: absolute; height: 100%".

Comment: edit that! What I thought worked didn't! I've created a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zYw3S/, in the home.html all there is, is a paragraph element with the lorem ipsum text.

Comment: Okay, try adding this: `#content{
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 70vh;

 }`  vh = View Height.  It's a percentage of your full view area.  It's different from % because it doesn't take into account the parent container.

Comment: Thanks man, adding the height: ..vh;, works exactly as I was aiming for :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set its `position: absolute;` and `top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;width: 100%;height: 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

Why is the right side of your div empty? Check whether you have applied width restrictions.
However,you can use *width:100%* so that the div fills the whole box. You might have to put your script inside another div and set the value of that div to 100%.